# How to access belongs_to model in class method that is called from the belongs_to model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

There are `User` and `Book` model, a user has many books and a book belongs to a user.

The `Book` has a class method `create_from_hash` and the method is called from `User` model.

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :books

  def create_book
    book_hash = {title: 'foo'}
    books.create_from_hash(book_hash)
  end
end

class Book < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  def self.create_from_hash(book_hash)
    # NameError: undefined local variable or method
    p user_id 
  end
end
```

How can I get `user_id` or `user` instance from the class method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass the user id to the create_from_hash method.

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :books

  def create_book
    book_hash = {title: 'foo'}
    books.create_from_hash(book_hash, self.id)
  end
end

class Book < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  def self.create_from_hash(book_hash, user_id)
    puts user_id
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass id with the `hash` and on the other side get it with `book_hash[:user_id]`

```rb
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :books

  def create_book
    book_hash = {title: 'foo', user_id: id}
    books.create_from_hash(book_hash)
  end
end

class Book < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  def self.create_from_hash(book_hash)
    p book_hash[:user_id]
  end
end
```